# Why is my View empty if the taxonomy term of a field on an entity is not set (i.e. 0)

Tags: 7, views

I am using ECK in Drupal 7 and I have an entity that has a property called "your_country".

- The behavior is "term_reference" (using the [eckextend](https://drupal.org/project/eckextend) module)
- The type is "integer",
- the widget type is "select list",
- the vocabulary is "countries", and
- the "Required property" is unticked (i.e. not required)

The database shows that this is an INT(11) not NULL and default value is "0"
[image]

It all works well with page manager but not so much with Views.

I created a view pane and added a relationship "your_country" because I need to fetch the "taxonomy **term name**" via that relationship. If I don't have that relationship, I can't show the term name.

It works but if that property was left 'empty' (the database shows "0"), then the view renders empty.

Why is that and how can I overcome that?

Comment: Did you set the Relationship to "Require"?

Comment: @prkos No, the relationship is not set to "require" that's why I find it strange. Perhaps it's because "0" is not a term that it therefore automatically hides that entity?

Comment: I've been thinking to create a term with term name "not set", put it at the front of the list and set it as the default, then hide the field with jQuery if that term is set. I understand that this doesn't really address the problem but it could be a temporary fix.

Comment: In the Field settings, under `No results behavior` there is the option `Count the number 0 as empty `. That should do it!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have just tried several options that relate to your suggestion and I came to find that if the relationship is NOT there, the view shows. How strange.

Comment: I probably have to mention that my view is View Pane but still, if the country is set, the pane shows, if it's not set, it doesn't.

Comment: Aren't taxonomy fields set up by default to have the name available? Through a formatter I think. Your symptoms sounds more like Contextual-filter-related and not Relationship-related. It's difficult to diagnose blind ;)